# PHP: Failed to retrieve auto increment id from database

Tags: php

I am creating a database fetch application and this is for test. All works fine but it fails to retrieve auto increment id from database. It says 'Undefined index id' if not defined id as null so i tried id = null but that shows nothing. My database has: email, password, id(AI, unique). What should i do to fetch id?

Code:

```
$email = "test@yahoo.com";
$password = "test";

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'users_database');

$query = "SELECT email, password FROM users_main_info WHERE email = '$email'";
$query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$em = null;
$pa = null;
$id = null;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $em = $row['email'];
    $pa = $row['password'];
}

echo $id;
```

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to correct your query:

```
$query = "SELECT id,email, password FROM users_main_info WHERE email = '$email'";
```

Try this I hope it will help.

Comment: no need to **try**!! it's what should be done

Comment: Your answer is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Ooops! That was a silly mistake! Thanks a lot bro. Will mark as answer after 13 minutes because of stackoverflow warning.

Comment: @RiggsFolly This was a simple test to fetch id. Actually i have done everything to protect my database information.

Comment: Not in the code you show us

Comment: @RiggsFolly My main file didn't work so created this test file to try if the result was same

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's in the main file bro. Chill!

Comment: Mean while we still have a question with very dubious coding in it, and a similiar answer that others may see and copy

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sir I didn't want to confuse a newbie with prepared statements.

Comment: I am not a newbie @HK007! I have a lots of PHP Experience!  I just did a silly mistake which i shouldn't repeat in near future!

Comment: @RiggsFolly OK, Bro!

Comment: @RiggsFolly I can't because i have marked HK007 answer as answered. Maybe among 7 billion some might find this useful :)